# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/-166733728/photo

Tags: android, facebook, photo, contacts

I've seen many answers, have tried many of them, but none with luck, sometimes I get file not found or

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/-166733728/photo, calling user:

Tried the following methods:

```
public static long getContactIDFromNumber(String contactNumber)

{   contactNumber = Uri.encode(contactNumber);
         long phoneContactID = new Random().nextInt();
            Cursor contactLookupCursor = myContext.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(contactNumber)),new String[] {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup._ID}, null, null, null);
                        while(contactLookupCursor.moveToNext()){
                            phoneContactID = contactLookupCursor.getInt(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup._ID));
                         }
                        contactLookupCursor.close();

   return phoneContactID;
            }




                public InputStream openThumbContact(long contactId) {
                    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
                    Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
                    Cursor cursor = myContext.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                         new String[] {Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor == null) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    try {
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
                            if (data != null) {
                                return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                public InputStream openDisplayPhotoContact(long contactId) {
                    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
                    Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);
                    try {
                        AssetFileDescriptor fd =
                            myContext.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r");
                        return fd.createInputStream();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long  id) { 
                    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id); 
                    InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
                     if (input == null) {  
                      return null;    
                     }
                     return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    }
```

Ideally I would like to show the thumb in the contacts or the one facebook has stored, does anyone have a working method? The contact photo is available in the contact list, but I can't get it to load.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this.